# How can I disallow guests to see other guests in share screen in a document library?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a specific client which is demanding that guest users must not see each other when accessing the share screen inside de folder shared with them. 
Today a guest can access the shared folder specific with him and open the share panel and them start typing on the grant access box which will show the names of other guest they should not be aware of. 
I basically need to turn off that share panel for guests or make sure they cannot don't see other guests in my Azure AD.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

The share button cannot be turned off, this is by design. However, you could disallow guests to share items they don't own.

Go to SharePoint new admin center-> sharing, uncheck the option "allow guests to share items they don't own"

[image]

The share panel for guest user would be like this:

[image]

Comment: I've already did this. I cannot let them access the share panel because they can use the search box (people picker) and see other guests, even though they are not able to complete the share procedure. The details panel has a manage access link and a Grant Access button that allows any user to do that.

Comment: Microsoft needs to disable the share panel as well from the design @AndreMorata did you find any solution yet?

Comment: @AmitKoyani nope... we had to segregate every group of users onto specific folder level.